# How do I print a wxImage with wxWidgets?

Tags: c++, image, printing, wxwidgets

I am writing a program using wxWidgets and I need to print a wxImage object. How do I do this? Also, the image needs to be scaled to fill the whole available print area? I tried to find some information on google and found [this](http://accountingplusplus.blogspot.com/2011/09/printing-images-with-wxwidgets.html).

However, I couldn't understand what to do based only on that page!
Any help would be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need fine control over printing, you must define your own [wxPrintout](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_printout.html)-derived class. The [printing sample](https://github.com/wxWidgets/wxWidgets/blob/WX_3_0_2/samples/printing/printing.cpp) shows how to do it and you really need to explain what exactly is your problem to get more help with solving it.

In many cases, using [wxHtmlEasyPrinting](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_html_easy_printing.html) can be enough, and is much easier -- but it won't take care of filling the image on its own, you will need to scale it yourself.